# Minimize button missing on Android SDK and AVD Manager when launched from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I recently switched my developing platfrom from win7 to ubuntu 11.04. Installation was pretty straight forward however I started notice things are different. First, the Android SDK and AVD Manager, when launched from Eclipse, does NOT have the minimze button. If I right click on the top bar, the minimize option is disabled. What's going on there? Although I can easily moved to another desktop so it doesn't interfere with coding, but it's annoying cause every time I click on the eclipse at the open window manager at the bottom of the screen, it automatically takes me to the SDK manager thinking it's the top most layer of eclipse. Any idea why that is?

Since I am on the top, also in eclipse, the bottom window segments (console, javadoc, etc) is also missing minimize button. I can minimize by double clicking the title tab of the editor, but for crying out loud, where is the minimize button for the bottom window segments. It has close, maximize, but no minimize. These are the moments that makes windows seems more superior than linux. Thoughts?

Comment: Please close this topic. It turns out, it was an ubuntu theme thing. Once I reset the theme back to default, everything worked as suppose to.

Answer (score 1):

You can just close it or if for some special reason you need it open just run `/opt/android-sdk/tools/android` (or whatever your path is) from your command line and not from Eclipse.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am doing now. I guess it's just a platform difference, it's just weird why they would leave out the mostly basic fundamental functionality such as minimize

Comment: No other dialog launched from the tool bar is minimizable, why are you expecting Adnroid SDK and AVD to be ?